# Same regex have different results in Java and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, regex

Same regex, different results;

Java

```java
String regex = "Windows(?=95|98|NT|2000)";
String str = "Windows2000";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
System.out.println(m.matches()); // print false
```

JavaScript

```js
var value = "Windows2000";
var reg = /Windows(?=95|98|NT|2000)/;
console.info(reg.test(value)); // print true
```

I can't understand why this is the case?

Comment: It could be because `matches()` returns true when the **whole** string to test matches. (the positive lookahead isn't part of the match)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation for Java's [`Matcher#matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) method:

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

The matcher API is trying to apply your pattern against the entire input.  This fails, because the RHS portion is a zero width positive lookahead.  So, it can match `Windows`, but the `2000` portion is not matched.

A better version of your Java code, to show that it isn't really "broken," would be this:

```
String regex = "Windows(?=95|98|NT|2000)";
String str = "Windows2000";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group()); // prints "Windows"
}
```

Now we see `Windows` being printed, which is the actual content which was matched.

Comment: @VishwaRatna Lookarounds are **zero width**, meaning _nothing_ will ever be captured/consumed from a lookahead (OK...there are exceptions, such as a backreference which was captured in a lookaround, but that's an edge case).  Just run my Java code and you will see what is happening here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  String#matcher() also returns false;